# Passing data from a route to determine dependency injection in controller constructor (Laravel 9)

Tags: laravel

Currently, I have a service that fulfills a contract promise to our resource controller's constructor parameter list, however the contract that is provided to the controller from the service is based upon the route that is being accessed (the contract is for an action file.)

Because of that, I currently have a switch statement reading the route and making logic choices off of that in the service file. I would much prefer to have something akin to middleware handle the action contract choice, in the same way that the router provides a controller file. As you may already know, Laravel now loads in the controller's constructor before any middleware is loaded, and I need a new way of tying the route to the action, if possible.

Example set up:

```
// WHAT I HAVE:
// Router
Route::apiResource('foo', App\Http\Controllers\FooController::class);
Route::apiResource('bar', App\Http\Controllers\BarController::class);
Route::apiResource('foo-bar', App\Http\Controllers\FooBarController::class);

// Service
...
switch ($this->getResourceNameFromRoute()) {
    case 'foo':
        switch ($request->getMethod()) {
            case 'GET':
                return new FooShowActionContract();
            case 'POST':
                return new FooUpdateActionContract();
            ...
        }
    case 'bar':
        ...
}

// FooController
public function __construct(?ActionContract $action = null)
{
    $this->action = $action;
}
```

how i would have like to solve this (but obviously, this will never work):

```
// Router
Route::apiResource('foo-bar', App\Http\Controllers\FooBarController::class)->middleware('actionMap:FooBarActionMap::class');

// Service
...
public function resolveContract()
{
    return app()->make(ActionContract::class, $request);
}

// FooController
public function __construct(?ActionContract $action = null)
{
    $this->action = $action;
}

// Middleware
public function handle($request, $next, $actionClassName)
{
    // bind an instance of the passed in class to the app for service to instantiate
}
```

Do you know of a way to do this, where I can pass in the contract class name from the route call? There has to be something more elegant than a switch statement that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that Action Contract? I think there is a miss use or something wrong hence a code smell, could you explain what are you then doing with that contract? How are you using it and why you need to do that?

Comment: Makes sense. It's not my design, and it's a bit wonky kind of smashing a few paterns together. Basically, each resource method is pulling its model, checking auth, and then setting the action's model with it to perform the action. Nothing crazy fancy, but the big kicker is they want to limit the number of files that have to be changed when a version change occurs, so preferably, the action file, router, and wherever the action selector ends up being.

Comment: Well, you can use the method itself, for example, `index` or `store`, etc, to inject the data, instead of using the constructor. Check [this out](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#method-injection) and let me know if it helped. The idea is to still do the same, use the middleware, but use the method to inject the object instead of the constructor